# Regex to find Markdown headings that don't end with anchors

Tags: regex

I am trying to search through Markdown files in VS Code looking for headings that do not have anchors at the end their lines
like this `[#some-anchor-name]`. To clarify, here is the shape of the headings I'm looking for:

- Headings that start with 1 to 4 `#` symbols (for example # or ###).
- Headings that have any number of characters following the `#` symbols, such as `## My Big Heading`
- Headings that do not end with the typical anchor pattern `[#some-anchor-name]`

Here are some regex I've tried:

This one almost works but it expects a literal space at the end of the heading with the missing anchor, which won't always be the case:

```
^#{1,4}.*\s(?!\[#.*\])$
```

The regex above matches on `## My Big Heading`  (note the space after the heading) which made me think I was going in the right direction.

I tried removing the search for the literal space just prior to the anchor and it matches on all my headings--even ones with anchors:

```
^#{1,4}.*(?!\[#.*\])$
```

For example, the regex above matches on `## My Big Heading` and `## My Big Heading [#my-big-anchor]`

To summarize, I'd like my regex to find line #2 below:

```
## My Big Heading [#my-big-anchor]
## My Big Heading
```

I looked at a variety of discussions on matching strings that don't have a particular pattern, but since I'm not matching a particular word at the end of the headings, they don't seem to apply:

- [Regular expression to match a line that doesn't contain a word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-a-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word)
- https://superuser.com/questions/1279062/regex-matching-line-not-containing-the-string

Comment: Try this: `/^#{1,4}.*\s+\w+/gm`. Here's a test: https://regex101.com/r/tT7m2j/1

Answer (score 2):

With your current pattern, the `.*\s` first matches until the end of the string, and then backtracks until the first occurrence of a whitespace char and then asserts that `[#...]` is not directly to the  right.

While that assertion is true for the space in between `Big Heading`, the `$` anchor right after it can not match.

---

You could write the pattern with the end of the string in the lookahead assertion:

```
^#{1,4}\s(?!.*\[#.*\]$).*
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `#{1,4}` Match 1-4 times a `#` char
- `\s` Match a whitespace char
- `(?!.*\[#.*\]$)` Negative lookahead, assert from the current position that the string does not end with `[#...]`
- `.*` Match the rest of the line

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Hv6GhW/1)

Answer (score 0):

What you should avoid is using `.*` (zero or more sequences of any character except a new line) and use instead `[^\[]*` (zero or more sequences of any character except an opening square bracket).

This is because the .* pattern does not play nice with your negative look-ahead.

As long as your normal headings does not have an opening square bracket character, you can use the following simple regex: `^#{1,4}[^\[]+$`. It does not use negative look-ahead assertion pattern.